# passing list to function, direct and indirect

Tags: python, list, nested

I have the following function:

```
def search_stmts(stmts,lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura = -1,higher_bound_aya = -1):
     ayas_list = []
     cnt = 0
     for cnt in range(len(stmts[0])):
         if stmts[0][cnt] == "root":
             ayas_list.append(self.root_lookup(stmts[1][cnt], basicrecord_instance.get_ayas_with_addressing( \
                                lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura, higher_bound_aya)))
         elif stmts[0][cnt] == "word":
             #print(stmts[1][cnt])
             ayas_list.append(self.word_lookup(stmts[1][cnt], basicrecord_instance.get_ayas_with_addressing( \
                                   lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura, higher_bound_aya)))

     return self.search_ayas(ayas_list)
```

It get the `stmts` as nested list: `[['word','root','word'],['hello','how','are']]` and 4 `int` arguments.

When I call my function as:

```
search_stmts([['word','word','root'],['hello','how','are']],1,1)
```

The above call works fine.

But if I have the following calling, It doesn't get any data:

```
list1 = ['root','word','root']
list2 = ['hello','how','are']
search_stmts([list1,list2],1,1)
```

How can I pass my two list as a one list?

Comment: Those two forms are exactly equivalent - except that you've changed the data slightly ('hello' is now a 'root' instead of a 'word').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the exact results if I removed "basicrecord_instance" and fucntions with "self"

```
def search_stmts(stmts,lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura = -1,higher_bound_aya = -1):
     ayas_list = []
     cnt = 0
     print(range(len(stmts[0])))
     for cnt in range(len(stmts[0])):
         print(cnt)
         if stmts[0][cnt] == "root":
             ayas_list.append((stmts[1][cnt], lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura, higher_bound_aya))
         elif stmts[0][cnt] == "word":
             #print(stmts[1][cnt])
             ayas_list.append((stmts[1][cnt],                                    lower_bound_sura,lower_bound_aya,higher_bound_sura, higher_bound_aya))
     return ayas_list

print(search_stmts([['word','word','root'],['hello','how','are']],1,1))
list1 = ['root','word','root']
list2 = ['hello','how','are']


print(search_stmts([list1,list2],1,1))
```

and I'm getting

```
[('hello', 1, 1, -1, -1), ('how', 1, 1, -1, -1), ('are', 1, 1, -1, -1)]
[('hello', 1, 1, -1, -1), ('how', 1, 1, -1, -1), ('are', 1, 1, -1, -1)]
```

Comment: self.word_lookup, basicrecord_instance.get_ayas_with_addressing, self.search_ayas are the only functions I've removed, and those two lines are giving me the same results. So it might be these functions that are making the result different?